# Casting an object to a reference?

Tags: c++, casting, reference

I've been reading some OSS code lately and stumbled upon this peculiar piece:

```
class Foo { ..... };
void bar() {
    Foo x;
   Foo *y=new Foo();
   x=(const Foo &) *y;
}
```

For the life of me I can't find documentation about the behavior of casting an object to a const reference.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the piece of code I found.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing (overlooking) the dereference on `y`?

Comment: Ouch, indeed I am. yet I still don't know what casting an object to a const reference means...

Comment: Any time you see a C-style cast in C++ code, it is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Does `Foo` have non-default `operator=`?

Comment: @Afiefh: so, with your edit, do you still need the code explained? Otherwise, it might be nice to delete the question entirely, as it doesn't serve any purpose when you're asking about code that's only weird because you misread it.

Comment: Does it have separate implementation of `operator=` for arguments of type `Foo &` and `const Foo &`?

Comment: @n0rd: check his edit. There's no mystery

Comment: Jalf: Yes, I still don't know what it does. I'll delete the question in a few minutes if no one answers.

Comment: @Afiefh: if you have a genuine question, don't delete it (but instead of just putting an "edit" at the bottom, update the entire question so it is clear what you're asking. We don't care that you misread the code 20 minutes ago, what we want to know is what your question *now* is.

Comment: I edited your question so the first code snippet matches the *actual* code, and removed the explicit edit. I didn't change the question text, so please update it if it doesn't reflect what you wanted to ask.

Comment: @jalf: I rolled back since it defeats the purpose of the question and got a reason why the original (misread) version would even work. :)

Comment: @Xeo: but as it is now, the question doesn't match the answer. The question is about "casting pointer to reference", and the accepted answer is about "assigning a reference to a value, with a cast stuck in between for no particular reason".

Comment: @Afiefh: please decide what you want to ask, and remove any information *not* related to that. If you want to know about "casting a pointer to a reference", then the edit is just misleading, and should be removed. If you want to understand the *actual* code, then the edit is what matters, and the rest of the question should be updated to match that. And of course, the accepted answer should be the one that answers the question you're actually asking. As it is now, it's just confusing.

Comment: @Afiefh: thanks, it's a lot clearer now what it is we're actually supposed to answer. (And with that, I turned my downvote into an upvote) :)

Comment: @jalf: Thanks, I don't usually make such mistake and didn't know what the acceptable stackoverflow etiquette required me to do. I thought I'd preserve the original text and add the new information so that anybody reading this afterwards wouldn't feel like some of the stuff here is not relevant to the post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`x=(const Foo &) *y;` is *assignment*. The only reason I see to explicitly cast to const reference is to have `Foo::operator=(const Foo &)` called for assignment if `Foo::operator=(Foo &)` also exists.

Answer (score 6):

`x=(const Foo &) y;` line invokes undefined behavior.
Prefer to avoid C-style casts; they are easy to get wrong. You silence the compiler, so they are too dangerous.

Edit: this answer was relevant at the time, when in the question `y` was not dereferenced prior to the cast to `const Foo &`. For the answer to the question after `*y` edit, please see the answer given by n0rd

Comment: @jalf: Compiles for me with g++ 4.4.5.  Why do you think it shouldn't?

Comment: Why do you think it should? I accept that it compiles under 3 major compilers (which surprised me), but I still don't see why it should. What in the standard allows a cast from pointer to reference type?

Comment: Don't see why this is undefined behavior. Its not nice because of the C style cast. But re-writing to use const_cast<> (its still not nice) but it still works.

Comment: Ok, after a few questions on the SO C++ chat, and 10 minutes spent reading the standard, and another 5 working through a toy example by hand, I get it. Yes, it compiles, and yes, it's undefined behavior. It turns into a `reinterpret_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast` to a reference type is equivalent to casting the address of the argument to a pointer to the target type, and then dereferencing it. So it is effectively casting from `Foo**` to `Foo*` which is well-formed because `reinterpret_cast` can cast between pointer types freely, and then dereferencing the result, yielding UB

Comment: @jalf: You are going to have to explain it then (So we do not need to also poor over the standard). To me it looks like the C-Cast should be converted into a simple const_cast<>

Comment: @Martin: Yes, you are right - it's converted into `const_cast`. `*y` yields lvalue of type `Foo` and the cast just adds const.

Comment: @jalf, @Martin, @Vitus: Thanks for great discussion while I was offline. The reason I was certain it compiled and was UB without looking up the standard was because I knew how `boost::addressof` was implemented. Essentially it casts its argument to `char &`, takes the address of the result and casts it to pointer to argument type. Now checking that with the standard, I see the relevant section is 5.2.10/10.

Comment: @Vitus: the tricky part happens because it's converted into a `reinterpret_cast`. There's little magic in the `const` being added

Comment: @Vitus, @usta: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924248/why-is-it-allowed-to-cast-a-pointer-to-a-reference). :)

Comment: @Xeo, @jalf: The pointer is dereferenced prior to the cast, so this should be valid `const_cast`. The dereference was probably added in question edit. :)

Comment: @Xeo: Very good follow-up question, with an excellent answer from @AndreyT ! +1

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, the misread code could still be possible, if `Foo` has a non-explicit constructor that takes a `Foo*` pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
public:
  Foo() {}
  Foo(Foo*) { std::cout << "Aha!\n"; }
};

int main(){
  Foo* pf = new Foo;
  Foo f = (const Foo&)pf;

  std::cin.get();
}
```

See the output [at Ideone](http://ideone.com/tCAv2).
Interestingly, if you make the constructor explicit, it shows the undefined behaviour explained by @usta.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to declare `x` after `y`:

```
Foo* y = new Foo();
Foo& x = *y;
```

Alternatively:

```
Foo x;
Foo* y = new Foo();
x = (Foo&)*y;
```

Comment: Note that I didn't write this, I'm trying to understand it and it is working the way it is written right now.

Comment: This isn't his code, he's trying to find an explanation on what it does.