# Why does this pointer_cast fail?

Tags: visual-c++, casting, mfc

This `if` test works fine (has done for years):

```
if (m_pMapSPtrEvents->Lookup(strKey, (void*&)psEvent))
{
    if (psEvent != nullptr)
    {
        bActivate = TRUE;
        strTipText = psEvent->strEvent;
    }
}
```

But if I change it to:

```
if (m_pMapSPtrEvents->Lookup(strKey, pointer_cast<void*&>(psEvent)))
{
    if (psEvent != nullptr)
    {
        bActivate = TRUE;
        strTipText = psEvent->strEvent;
    }
}
```

Where `pointer_cast is:

```
template<typename T, typename U> static T inline pointer_cast(U src) noexcept
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) >= sizeof(U), "Invalid pointer cast"); // Check sizes!
    __pragma(warning(suppress:26490)) // Note: no semicolon after this expression!
        return reinterpret_cast<T>(src);
}
```

It fails. What is the modern way of of casting my structure pointer (`SPECIAL_EVENT_S *psEvent`)?

`m_pMapSPtrEvents` is of type `CMapStringToPtr`.

---

I should point out:

- I get no visual warnings in the IDE.
- It compiles with no errors.
- It does not assert when I run it.
- But it will not detect that `if` clause and thus a tooltip does not display.

... unless I revert to the c-style cast.

---

#### Update

If I remove the `&` as suggested I get build errors:

```
4>MyMonthCalCtrl.cpp
4>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\MyMonthCalCtrl.cpp(72,8): error C2664: 'BOOL CMapStringToPtr::Lookup(LPCTSTR,void *&) const': cannot convert argument 2 from 'T' to 'void *&'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            T=void *
4>        ]
4>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30704\atlmfc\include\afxcoll.h(1264,7): message : see declaration of 'CMapStringToPtr::Lookup'
4>Done building project "Meeting Schedule Assistant.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the reference specification (the `&`) in the cast? I guess the `Lookup` function call will make a reference, anyway.

Comment: Using `reinterpret_cast` with a reference type [is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924278/10871073); using it with a reference to a pointer type is even weirder.

Comment: @AdrianMole I have only been using `pointer_cast` becuase that is what we came up with a few weeks ago. `static_cast` will not work.

Comment: I know. But I think the reference type is somehow confusing things. If, as suggested in the answer I linked, there is some kind of undetected dereference of a `void*` type, then that'll be throwing all sort of spanners in all sorts of works. Maybe I'll need to revist the code for the `pointer_cast` ...

Comment: @AdrianMole Please do - I am in a sinking dingy without a paddle :)

Comment: @AdrianMole Do you still want me to try the first suggestion, or wait?

Comment: Please try. If it works, then that could help.

Comment: @AdrianMole Doesn't work - see updated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238466/discussion-between-adrian-mole-and-andrew-truckle).

Comment: That function does look strange with `return reinterpret_cast<T>(src)`, I get a warning *"returning address of local variable or temporary: src"*. Try using `m_pMapSPtrEvents->Lookup(strKey, reinterpret_cast<void*&>(psEvent))`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani 1. Using that suggested code functions correctly. 2. I had noticed that warning during building and had not raised it for discussion yet. I use `pointer_cast` quite a bit in this app now but feel that would be a distinct question?

Comment: @AdrianMole Please see Barmak comment.

Comment: Yeah - need to re-think the `pointer_cast` to handle reference type conversions. I'll see if I can come up with at least a `quick-fix` that warns/fails on such types, though ...

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks because at the moment I won't know which bits of my application are silently not working.

Comment: As a stop-gap, you can add this as the first line of the `pointer_cast` function: `static_assert(!std::is_reference<T>::value, "Cannot pointer_cast to a reference!");` (you'll need also to `#include <type_traits>`).

Comment: @AdrianMole OK, will try tomorrow. Need to go to work (night shift).

Comment: Try `template<typename T, typename U> static T inline pointer_cast(U& src)`, taking the parameter by reference. I think as written, the function takes its parameter by value, and then returns a reference to the local variable, not to `psEvent`

Comment: @Igor Yeah - that would be a problem. I've been messing around with various ways to handle returning a reference but the problem is *always* that the function ends up returning a reference to the copy that's been made (of the argument) on the stack. Your solution is simple and looks good ... will try some tests and get back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure someone will collate an answer that describes *why* `pointer_cast` fails — they'll be better able to explain than me.

---

#### Workaround

My answer provides the workaround. Given the context of these warnings (MFC Application) and given the fact there are valid instances where [`reinterpret_cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/reinterpret-cast-operator?view=msvc-160) must be used, I have added the following line to my `stdafx.h` file:

`#pragma warning( disable : 26490)`

And used Find / Replace to revert all `pointer_cast` to `reinterpret_cast`. The application is functioning OK now.