# Safe and efficient way to use SIMD intrinsics on an exisiting float array

Tags: c++, simd, sse, intrinsics

I am learning about SSE and AVX to further improve the performance of some of the computations in my code.

However, I have come across multiple different ways to use the SSE instructions on an existing array of floats. I would like to know which of these are safe (no UB) and efficient. I have marked the lines of code that's different across versions with a **<-- arrow** comment. Also given a link to godbolt example.

**Version 1 :- Using _mm_load**

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    __m128 simd = _mm_set1_ps(10.0f) ;
    alignas(16) float float_arr[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3} ;
    __m128 load_simd = _mm_load_ps(float_arr) ; // <-------
    __m128 sum = _mm_add_ps(simd, load_simd) ;
    alignas(16) float float_arr_sum[4] ;
    _mm_store_ps(float_arr_sum, sum) ;
    std::cout << float_arr_sum[0] << ", " << float_arr_sum[1] << ", " << float_arr_sum[2] << ", " << float_arr_sum[3] << std::endl ;
}
```

**Version 2 :- Using __m128& (reference)**

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    __m128 simd = _mm_set1_ps(10.0f) ;
    alignas(16) float float_arr[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3} ;
    __m128& cast_ref_simd = reinterpret_cast<__m128&>(float_arr[0]) ; // <-----
    __m128 sum = _mm_add_ps(simd, cast_ref_simd) ;
    alignas(16) float float_arr_sum[4] ;
    _mm_store_ps(float_arr_sum, sum) ;
    std::cout << float_arr_sum[0] << ", " << float_arr_sum[1] << ", " << float_arr_sum[2] << ", " << float_arr_sum[3] << std::endl ;
}
```

**Version 3 :- Using __m128* (pointer)**

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    __m128 simd = _mm_set1_ps(10.0f) ;
    alignas(16) float float_arr[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3} ;
    __m128* cast_ptr_simd = reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(float_arr) ; // <-------
    __m128 sum = _mm_add_ps(simd, *cast_ptr_simd) ; // <-------
    alignas(16) float float_arr_sum[4] ;
    _mm_store_ps(float_arr_sum, sum) ;
    std::cout << float_arr_sum[0] << ", " << float_arr_sum[1] << ", " << float_arr_sum[2] << ", " << float_arr_sum[3] << std::endl ;
}
```

I tested all these in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jqE58Krjc) and saw that for versions **2** and **3** there is an extra instruction of moves ( `movaps`, move aligned packed single-precision floating-point) between xmm0 and xmm1 registers. They also generate the same assembly output.
For optimizations including and above 1 (`-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`...), all three versions generate the same code.

For my project I am using `-O3`, so I guess the compiled output will not change but I want to have a proper understanding if possible.

I am also looking at some popular extra libraries like [Agner Fog's header only lib](https://github.com/vectorclass/version2) and [Vc](https://github.com/VcDevel/Vc)(which will become `std::simd` at some point) but I want to learn some low-level experience before using them.

Comment: Side note : The number of instructions is not the most important metric. And you might be surprised how good compilers can be at vectorization already. So be sure to always profile the compilers generated solution and the handwritten solution written by yourself.

Comment: But what is your real question?

Comment: It's useless to look at unoptimized asm, especially from intrinsics, since `_mm_load_ps` is an actual function wrapped around the dereference, which will only optimize away if you enable optimization.  These are all equivalent; `_mm_load_ps` is definitely more idiomatic; it's normal to have `__m128` variables for a load result.  (And if you want to use unaligned loads, you'll want `_mm_loadu_ps`).  Basically a duplicate of [Is \`reinterpret\_cast\`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112605) (no)

Comment: @PepijnKramer The question is "I would like to know which of these versions are safe (no UB) and efficient"

Comment: BTW, all your code optimizes away here.  Write a function that takes a `float*` arg or two and loads + stores, if you want to see the compiler actually do something.  Not a `main` with constants.  If you just want to look at the asm to see how a function compiles, you want a function, not a whole program.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: All 3 versions are exactly equivalent as far as the compiler is concerned.  (Unless you disable optimization, then the `_mm_load_ps` version has an extra return-value object that has to exist in the asm.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the reply. So all these are well-defined and completely safe to use and even equivalent when optimizations are enabled? For me personally, the reference version looks a bit strange.

Comment: Yes.  They're equivalent *as far as the compiler is concerned*, so make your choice based on human readers.  I'd highly recommend never using the reference version; I had to look carefully at it to figure out WTF that was doing.  And I'm only 99% sure the reference version is fully safe; it seems weird to be binding a 128-bit reference to a 32-bit float.  The two other versions are definitely equivalent, though.  `_mm_loadu_ps( &arr[i] )` is a common idiom.

Comment: @PeterCordes TBH the reference version was the version I was taught from my HPC course. I never really understood how it worked. For pointers I can make sense on how the 4 floats are reinterpreted as `__m128` but for reference it seemed a bit strange. Nonetheless it works and generated same asm as the pointer version

Comment: Using a reference instead of a load seems like a terrible habit.  Usually you want the compiler to load once, not keep re-referencing memory every time you read a variable, even after storing to other locations.  Using a reference would force it to do alias analysis (figure out two arrays can't overlap, or that a specific store can't overlap with any `__m128&` references) if it wants to optimize the referenced `__m128` value into a register that only gets loaded once in the asm.  (It's still exactly equivalent here because you only read the reference once, with no intervening stores.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 3 versions are exactly equivalent to the compiler in this use-case where you only read the reference / deref the pointer once, without doing any stores between it and the cast or load.

See [Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond) (no UB, it's safe.)

---

**So the choice comes down to style and readability**.  `_mm_load_ps`, or `_mm_loadu_ps` for unaligned, are standard.  The compiler can still fold a `_mm_load_ps` into a memory source operand for `addps xmm0, [rdi]` or whatever.

If you cast to raw `__m128 *p` and deref with `*p`, that only works for aligned (equivalent to `_mm_load_ps` not `loadu`).  If you wanted to modify your code to allow an unaligned input (e.g. a pointer to the middle of an array, which is something you might want even if all your arrays are aligned), you'd have to change your code significantly to use `_mm_loadu_ps`.  That intrinsic wants a `float*`, so you'd actually have to cast `_mm_loadu_ps( (float*)p )`.

Some people like to increment a `__m128i *ptr` through their array for integer where the `load[u]` / `store[u]` intrinsics take `__m128i*` rather than `void*`.  But most code still uses the load / store intrinsics instead of a raw deref, mostly just to make it more visible.

**Using a reference instead of a load seems like a terrible habit**. Usually you want the compiler to load once, not keep re-referencing memory every time you read a variable, even after storing to other locations. Using a reference would force it to do alias analysis (figure out two arrays can't overlap, or that a specific store can't overlap with any `__m128&` references) if it wants to optimize the referenced `__m128` value into a register that only gets loaded once in the asm. (It's still exactly equivalent here because you only read the reference once, with no intervening stores.)

A `__m128` reference is unusual and would easily be confusing.  People maintaining the code later might forget that it's a reference not a load result, and introduce bugs by reading it again after a store that might overlap.  Or at least make code less efficient if the compiler loads again because it can't *prove* that a store couldn't have been pointing to the referenced floats.

I tend to write either of these ways

```
    __m128 v = _mm_load_ps( ptr );    // when doing pointer increments
// or
    __m128 v = _mm_load_ps( &arr[i] );  // when using integer indices

// then do stuff to the load result, maybe declaring other __m128 temporaries
```

Since you do often want to declare other `__m128` temporaries when you're doing something non-trivial, it's nice to have the load result be another `__m128` like those, so using it multiple times hints the compiler in the direction of loading once into a register.  It might still optimize multiple `*ptr` derefs into one load, but writing the source as close as possible to the efficient asm that I want seems like a good idea and sometimes helps.  A `__m128 &v` reference would be even worse, hiding the difference between reading a local var which is hopefully in a register vs. re-accessing memory.

For trivial stuff, compilers normally auto-vectorize pretty well so you often don't need intrinsics at all.

---

It's useless to look at unoptimized asm, especially from intrinsics, since `_mm_load_ps` is an actual function wrapped around the dereference.  It will optimize away if you enable optimization, but if not there's an extra return-value object that might [make the anti-optimized debug-build asm even worse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073295/why-is-this-c-wrapper-class-not-being-inlined-away).  Intrinsics with optimization disabled is a total disaster for asm efficiency in general.

Comment: (This mostly re-states what I already wrote in comments under the question; I decided to post it as an answer that emphasizes the style difference.)

Comment: The reference version is the same as the pointer version. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924278/17843293
Apparently the standard defines them to be the same