# Difference between returning *this by reference and value

Tags: c++, pointers

if there difference between followed code samples?

```
ClassTwo ClassTwo::getOwnOne(){
    return *this;
}


 ClassTwo& ClassTwo::getOwnTwo(){
    return *this;
}
```

if there difference between followed code samples? is it same?

Comment: Could anybody who downvoted explain why in a comment?

Comment: @HXCaine I didn't downvote, but the original question title was poorly worded and it quickly accumulated downvotes, so I fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

```
ClassTwo ClassTwo::getOwnOne()
```

This returns a *copy* of the object it's called on.

```
ClassTwo& ClassTwo::getOwnTwo()
```

This returns a *reference* to the object it's called on.

They both do (more or less) the same thing if you use the result to create a new object:

```
ClassTwo c2a = c2.getOwnOne(); // New object
ClassTwo c2b = c2.getOwnTwo(); // New object too
```

but are different if you use them to initialise a reference:

```
ClassTwo const & c2a = c2.getOwnOne(); // New object (lifetime tied to reference)
ClassTwo const & c2b = c2.getOwnTwo(); // Reference to c2

ClassTwo & c2a = c2.getOwnOne(); // ERROR
ClassTwo & c2b = c2.getOwnTwo(); // Reference to c2
```

The third is an error because you can't bind a mutable reference to a temporary object.

Comment: Even if you ignore the results, the version returning by value will construct a new `ClassTwo` to return.  If `ClassTwo` doesn't support copy, it won't compile, and if the copy constructor does anything that is in any way visible, that will happen.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, I oversimplified a bit there.

Answer (score 3):

The first one copies `*this`, the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

They are *not* the same. The first one will implicitly call the copy constructor and return a *copy* of the object. The second one will return a *reference* to it.

You can verify this by adding a copy constuctor to your class, something like this (a useless one, just to display a message):

```
ClassTwo(const ClassTwo& in)
{
  cout << "I am the copy constructor" << endl;
}
```

If you call your `getOwnOne()` method, it will display the message. The `getOwnTwo()` wont.

Answer (score 2):

The first definition returns a copy of the object you are calling getOwnOne on. This means you'll be calling the class' constructor when you call this method.

The second method returns a reference to the object you're calling getOwnTwo on.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923702/casting-an-object-to-a-reference).  <strike>The second class can have Undefined Behaviour</strike>

Maybe since you get the same output with either. It makes you think they are same.

The first one returns the `current object` whereas the second one will typecast the returned object to its reference

Comment: No, there's no undefined behaviour here; returning a reference to a (non-local) object is fine. Nor is there any in the unrelated question you link to, despite the dodgy cast making it look like there could be.